# remove all elements in array where the first 2 characters are e.g. BB

Tags: php, arrays

I've an array like this, and I want to delete the records with e.g. BB from the array. (at the end with the use of a variable for the two letters)

```
$arrRange = array(AA first, AA second, AA third, BB first, BB second, BB third, ...);
```

I've tried several things but didn't manage so far. I've started with this, but then all elements are removed. Anyone a suggestion?

```
foreach($arrRange as $a){
     if (substr($a, 0, 2) === 'BB'){
            $arrRange = array_diff($arrRange, $a);         
     } 
}
```

Comment: The answer of Vanya was to the point. I can now use it with a variable e.g. $letters = 'BB'; I want to go a step further and want to use this with an array variable $letters= array('BB', 'EE', 'HH'); and so more elements could be filtered out. I've tried some options, but so far didn't manage. Would this be possible to solve this with an extra foreach loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($arrRange as $key=>$a){
     if (substr($a, 0, 2) === 'BB'){
            unset($arrRange[$key]);
     } 
}
```